# Bonding device to box when using EMT as EGC

Tags: electrical

I have an outlet run using EMT as the EGC to a metal box.  Once I'm at the box do I need to connect a wire from the device to the metal box, or is the grounding ear of the device a sufficient ground path?

EDIT: Thanks to Manassehkatz for the answer below.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving 2 Codidact: Thank you for the answer, that provides me with much satisfaction.

Answer (score 5):

- Switches with metal yoke - Screw in yoke and done.
- Receptacles marked as "self grounding" - Screw in yoke and done.
- Receptacles *not* marked as "self grounding" - Attach a green or bare wire from the ground screw to a ground screw in the box.
- Any device that has a plastic yoke - Attach a green or bare wire from the ground screw to a ground screw in the box.
- Any device that includes a ground wire permanently attached - Attach it to a ground screw in the box.

Note that the same receptacles that are marked as "self grounding" typically:

- Cost $1 - $3 more than "basic" receptacles
- Are better built than "basic" receptacles
- Often include "screw to clamp" so that you can put the hot and neutral wires straight in underneath screws rather than having to (a) make hooks to put under screws or (b) use backstab connections which are notoriously unreliable (and usually have limited allowable wire size).

So you use better quality receptacles and you will rarely have to connect a separate ground wire to a metal box.

Comment: Well, my work is done here :)

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica You have trained me well.